# Proving $\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence with the terms

$$
a_{n}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
n, & \text { if } n \text { even } \\
\frac{1}{n}, & \text { if } n \text { odd }
\end{array}\right.
$$

Prove $\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} = \infty$.

I will like to have some help. Intuitively this makes sense: the upper bound of the set consists of $a_n$ is $\infty$. Because there is infinitely many even natural numbers. I can also explain this a bit more thoroughly verbally. But is it possible to make an $\epsilon$-proof? I have a good grasp of $\epsilon$-proof when it comes to convergence of sequences, but I do not have any experience with limes superior.

Please help,

Kind regards

Comment: Did you mean $\limsup$?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I'm going to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $\limsup a_n$ is the largest limit of a subsequence. But we have the sequence $(n)_{n=1}^\infty$ as subsequence of even terms and this tends to $+\infty$. Thus we must have $\limsup_n a_n=+\infty$.

Alternatively,

$$\limsup_n a_n = \inf_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{k=n}^\infty a_k =\inf \{\infty\}=\infty$$

Yet another alternative,

$$\limsup_n a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup\{a_k:k\geq n\}=\lim_{n\to \infty} +\infty=+\infty$$

Exercise using the same reasoning: Show $\liminf_n a_n=0$.

Comment: I have corrected it. It is limb soup.

Comment: But how is this a proof? 

Comment: The limsup is the largest limit of a subsequence. Here we have a subsequence with limit $\infty$, so $\limsup_n a_n\geq \infty$. Then of course $\limsup_n a_n =+\infty$. I added an alternative proof though.

Comment: Okay, thank. But I think you have made a typo in LaTeX in the answer you just have given.

Comment: What typo? I don't see any.

Comment: This: $$
\inf _{n=1}^{\infty} \sup _{k=n} a_{k}
$$

Maybe it is just me. I have never seen this.

Comment: No that's correct. What is your definition of limsup if I may ask?

Comment: $$
\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}:=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \sup \left\{a_{n}: n \geq N\right\}
$$

Sorry, my brain is a bit cooked today.

Comment: Ok, we have $\limsup_n a_n:=\lim v_n$ where $v_n =\sup_{k=n}^\infty a_k$. Note that $(v_n)_n$ is a decreasing sequence so $\lim_n v_n =\inf_n v_n$. Do you now see why what I wrote in my answer holds?

Comment: Could you be kind and write you answer with the definition  I gave you. I can NOT manage to compare these two definitions.

Comment: I did. Now you have three answers.

Comment: I dislike your definition though because you then have to define limits of sequences with values that may be infinite.

Comment: That is actually the Idea. To expand the real numbers to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$

Comment: Alright. Is my answer now clear to you?

Comment: Yes, it is. I think it was a notation thing. Thank you for your time. Good explanation also 

Comment: No problem. Glad to be able to help!

Comment: I suggest to come back in a while and reread the answer. Maybe the other techniques will be clear then.

Comment: Yes, I usually do that if I still remember .

Answer (score 2):

$b_n:= \sup \{a_k: k\ge n \}\ge n.$

$\lim \sup \{a_n\}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n \ge \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n =\infty.$

Comment: I just saw this. I actually understand this even though there is not a lot of word  Thank you.

Comment: Xenusi. Welcome:)